# Obtaining the search region of the latin_hypercube grid function

Tags: hyperparameters, tidymodels

I use `tune_grid()` with no parameter grid to tune my hyperparameters (see below, please). According to the help page of the `tune_grid()` function, a parameter grid will be created using `dials::grid_latin_hypercube()`. I understand (please correct me if I am wrong) that the hypercube function divides the search region into equal subdivisions and randomly picks values from each of these subdivisions. I need to obtain the range of each of these subdivisions. How can I obtain that?

```
set.seed(345)
Data_RF_fit <- 
  Data_RF_wflow %>% 
  tune_grid(val_set,
            grid = 25, 
            control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE),
            metrics = metric_set(rmse))

set.seed(345)
Data_KKNN_fit <- 
  Data_KKNN_wflow %>%  
  tune_grid(val_set,
            grid = 25,
            control = control_grid(save_pred = TRUE),
            metrics = metric_set(rmse))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function grid_latin_hypercube() creates a grid based on the ranges of the input values that you set. If you don't set any value, it will use the default ranges.

In your case, since I believe you're using k-nearest neighbors, you can check these values using `?nearest_neighbors` to find the tunable hyperparameters. Since these hyperparameters in tidymodels can be ran as commands in the console, you can either check each option by running it as a command, which will output its default state, or check its help page.

So, for example, if you wanted to check the defaults for the `neighbors` parameter you could either run

```r
neighbors()
#> # Nearest Neighbors (quantitative)
#> Range: [1, 10]
```

or

```
?neighbors
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it seems either the ```tune_grid```, or another function, overrides the default range. For example, as you show above, the range of the ```neighbors``` parameter is [1,10], but when I check the parameter grid, I can see that for some parameter combinations the value of ```neighbors``` is larger than 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can `extract_parameter_set_dials()` from a workflow you have created, and then use that to see the parameter that is created:

```r
library(tidymodels)

knn_spec <-
    nearest_neighbor(neighbors = tune()) %>%
    set_mode("classification") %>%
    set_engine("kknn")

knn_wf <- workflow(Class ~ ., knn_spec)

pset <- extract_parameter_set_dials(knn_wf)
pset$object
#> [[1]]
#> # Nearest Neighbors (quantitative)
#> Range: [1, 15]
## if you need to compute on these:
pset$object[[1]]$range
#> $lower
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $upper
#> [1] 15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: If you want to get a specific parameter, use `extract_parameter_dials(knn_wf, "neighbors")`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer helps me solve my problem. However, my question is how a user can even know that such a function exists? If the code was in a language like Matlab, I could easily go to the debug mode and check what parameter values are input to the function. However, when I try the debug mode with Tideymodels, it is almost impossible to understand anything. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: We recommend checking out our documentation, like [this about tuning parameters](https://www.tmwr.org/tuning.html#tuning-params-tidymodels).